# I need an elegant solution to format race times

Tags: google-apps-script

I process race results and times often come in from race directors in various formats. I need to reprocess them. I have a function which sort of works, but I wonder if there's a better way.

I currently use the code below, which basically just finds and replaces the things I need. However, apart from being ugly, it has a problem.

Say I have a time of 13 minutes 45 seconds. This needs to read as 13:45. Sometimes it will come in as 13:45:00. Ok so I can strip off the trailing zeros and colon.

However, if I then get a time in of 13 hours 45 minutes and zero seconds, then 13:45:00 is completely legitimate and I want the trailing zeros to remain.

I am sure there must be a way to resolve this but I don't know how.

I'd be really grateful for your assistance. Thank you.

```
    function formatGunTimes() {

     var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange("J2:J");
     var v = range.getValues();
    for ( var r = 0; r < v.length; ++r) {
      v[r][0] = v[r][0].replace(".", ":");
      v[r][0] = v[r][0].replace(/^0/g, "");
      v[r][0] = v[r][0].replace(/^1:0/g, "6");
      v[r][0] = v[r][0].replace(/^1:1/g, "7");
      v[r][0] = v[r][0].replace(/^1:2/g, "8");
      v[r][0] = v[r][0].replace(/^1:3/g, "9");
      v[r][0] = v[r][0].replace(/^0:/g, "");
      v[r][0] = v[r][0].replace(/^:/g, "");
      v[r][0] = v[r][0].replace(/:0$/g, "");
      v[r][0] = v[r][0].replace(/^\s*$/g, "0");
      }
    range.setValues(v);
    }
```

Comment: How do these values "come in" to your spreadsheet? Surely if you're able to fix that, you won't need the script at all?

Comment: I copy and paste a csv or xls file sent to me by race directors into a sheet labelled Import. I have no control over how they record the data initially. From there the automation takes over to format at the relevant headers into a standardized format. This includes runner names, numbers, running club name, Gun time, Chip time, and age category. I used to have to do a lot of manual editing but now most of it is automated. I don't mind how, or where in the process the time formatting happens, I just need it to happen and be reliable!

Comment: Communicate the issue to the race directors and request them to enter data in a specific format.

Comment: @TheMaster Unfortunately not an option. Race results from all over the UK but Europe and rest of the world too. Thanks for your efforts and ideas though.

Comment: So what? Email all of them? Your question is also unclear. What's the final input data  received in the spreadsheet? `13:45:00` and `13:45:00`?  And what's the expected output? `13:45` and `13:45:00`? If so, there's no difference in input and nothing can be done to deduce the output from the input?

Comment: yes, I've come to that conclustion regarding number/time. So I've reverted to setting the numbers as plain text and using find and replace. This works well enough. Thank you all for your input.